# Assigning elements from the DOM to the constructor prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, dom

I want assign to my prototype DOM elements that are created with functions also on the prototype.

I have described all in comments below.

Summary: my prototype function should generate DOM elements, put them into body and immediately assign reference to them to prototype's property eg. Game.prototype.boxes = // newly created DOM elements.

```
function Game() {

    this.class = 'box';
    // this.boxes = this.createBoxes(); // It almost works, but isn't on prototype and is duplicated, when I create instance of Monstar class.

}

// Game.prototype.boxes = this.createBoxes(); // I know, in this context 'this' isn't my constructor, but this is method I want to achieve
// Game.prototype.boxes = $('.' + this.class); // As above - 'this' isn't my constructor
Game.prototype.boxes = Game.prototype.createBoxes(); // Alternative test from the lines above. It have to be on my prototype.

Game.prototype.createBoxes = function () {

    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for(var i  = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        var elem = $('<div>', {
            class: this.class
        });

        elem.appendTo(docFragment);

    }

    $(docFragment).appendTo($('body'));

    return $('.' + this.class);

};

function Monster() {

    Game.call(this);

    console.log(this.boxes); // Finally this should returns array with my DOM elements created using prototype createBoxes function.

}

Monster.prototype = Object.create(Game.prototype);
Monster.prototype.constructor = Monster;

var game = new Game(),
    monster = new Monster();

console.log(game.boxes); // Finally this should returns array with my DOM elements created using prototype createBoxes function.
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Surely you want to assign the object to a property of your *instance*, not to the global/static prototype? Why would you want DOM elements to be shared? Usually that's exactly what we want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `createBoxes` to be on the prototype. In fact, it doesn't need to stick around at all once it's done its job, so I'd just inline it (moving the `class` property from the instance to the function as well):

```
Game.class = "box";
Game.prototype.boxes = (function() {
    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(var i  = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var elem = $('<div>', {
            class: this.class
        });
        elem.appendTo(docFragment);
    }
    $(docFragment).appendTo($('body'));
    return $('.' + Game.class);
})();
```

I'm fairly sure you realize it, but just to emphasize: You'll have **one** array of boxes, which is shared by all instances of `Game` (and all instances of `Monster`, etc.).

If `class` were going to be different for every `Game`, then having `boxes` on the prototype wouldn't make any sense at all.

---

Here's the full code with that change:

```
function Game() {
}
Game.class = "box";
Game.prototype.boxes = (function() {
    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(var i  = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var elem = $('<div>', {
            class: this.class
        });
        elem.appendTo(docFragment);
    }
    $(docFragment).appendTo($('body'));
    return $('.' + Game.class);
})();

function Monster() {
    Game.call(this);
    console.log(this.boxes);
}
Monster.prototype = Object.create(Game.prototype);
Monster.prototype.constructor = Monster;

var game = new Game(),
    monster = new Monster();

console.log(game.boxes);
```

Comment: You'll also have to inline the `this.class` constant as `"box"`